# Add path to remote server in iOS app

Tags: ios, uiwebview, nsuserdefaults

I try to open a specific path in my app, but nothing is displayed in the UIWebView in my simulator, my orignal code is :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    NSString *host = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"host"];

    NSString* complement = @"/manager/";


    NSString *fullURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", host, complement];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_myWebview loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

Host is stored with the bundles settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1: When you have set the `NSUserDefaults` for the key `"host"`, have you also called `synchronize` on `NSUserDefaults`?

2: Please debug the variable `NSString *host`, is the right string in it?

3: Instead of `NSString *fullURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", host, complement];` try this `host = [host stringByAppendingString:complement];`

3.1: Is on your server this specific path available over Desktop Safari?/Is there some `index.html` at this path?

4: Please debug the variable `NSURL *url`, is the right string in it?

5: Implement all UIWebViews Delegates and debug them also: [UIWebViewDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:)

Comment: Ok , It's work with your help, an other essential question, if I want to replace /manager/ by a specific port, I the same method ? Or we need to use another ?

Comment: depends on you. If you want always add some strings to your host, than you can use this method above. BUT! If you saving `host/manager/` and want to replace `/manager/` by Port `1337`, than you have to use `host = [host stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/manager/" withString:@":1337"];`

Comment: I obtain that : `Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)" UserInfo=0x7a99c470 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://xx.xx.xxx.xx:9092, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://xx.xxx.xx.xx:9092, NSUnderlyingError=0x7a829170 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error -1012.)"}` maybe because there is an htpasswd auth ? But when I try in safari it's work

Comment: Can you reach this site in a browser which you never use? Probably you have save your htpasswd credentials in safari, so safari will not longer ask you for authentication.

Comment: With another browser I can load the ip (I try to contact my server in a specific port ) , in this browser ( chrome ) The auth is displayed and I can view the page after the authentifiaction

Comment: I'm not a pro in http requests, but I think you can give your auth informations over the url. TAKE CARE! http connections can be sniffed and your auth credentials are in plain text. So maybe you need SSL. But for this Issue ( htpasswd in a url request ) try to take google, as I am not a pro in http request. Maybe for the first try, remove this security options in your browser to code on your project.